# Can we prevent shared mutable state if we only allow local variables to be mutable?

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, clojure, immutability

In a non-OOP programming language, like C, If we only allow local variables to be mutated in every possible way (change internal fields, re-assigning, ...) but disallow mutation of function arguments, will it help us prevent shared mutable state?

Note that in this case, function `main` can start 10 threads (functions) and each of those 10 threads will receive an immutable reference to the same variable (defined in `main`). But the `main` function can still change the value of that shared variable. So can this cause problem in a concurrent/parallel software?

I hope the question is clear, but let me know if it's not.

P.S. Can "software transactional memory (STM)" solve the potential problems? Like what Clojure offers?

Comment: `main` is no different from any other threads. So you have exactly the same multi-thread problems in the case described as you have if the individual threads changes a shared variable.

Comment: @4386427 notice the assumption that only one thread is allowed to write to the memory. All other threads only read... There are still issues (I'm writing an answer), but often people believe this helps.

Comment: If `main()` modifies the variable but the the threads are supposed to read different values from it, you've not resolved the problem.  This can be a problem with POSIX pthreads.  The `pthread_create()` function takes a `void *` last argument, and a common mistake is to pass the address of a loop control variable — which means that the threads cannot tell what they're going read (the value may have changed between when the function was invoked and the thread is started).

Comment: @Myst you are right. Only one thread (the `main` thread) can write. Others can only read.

Comment: this doesn't solve anything

Comment: @mahdix , thanks for making it clear. I don't think this offers enough protection for the code, even when combined with the `volatile` keyword, as explained in my answer.

Comment: @Myst Makes no difference.... As soon as one thread (incl. `main`) writes a variable that other threads are reading, all the usual multi-threading problems exists. There are no platform independent work-around for that. You'll always have to protect the access (e.g. mutex, atomic).

Comment: @4386427 I agree (see my answer)... but the question does represent a common misconception about memory reading , as if the worst that could happen is a valid (if less updated) value.

Comment: @mahdix - You shouldn't have deleted your `TryParse` question. I think you just needed to get the question quality up a little more and it would have been an interesting question.

Comment: @Enigmativity You are right but the feedback I received was a bit more harsh than I expected.

Comment: @mahdix - Your question was confusing and not at all clearly stated. It was of quite poor quality. You need to think through your question more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no... this depends on the platform, the CPU, the size of the shared variable and the compiler.

On an [NVIDIA forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1001470/cuda-programming-and-performance/partial-read-from-global-memory-when-spin-locking-/), in relation to GPU operations, a similar question was very neatly answered:

> When multiple threads are writing or reading to/from a naturally aligned location in global memory, and the datatype being read or written is the same by all threads, and the datatype corresponds to one of the supported types for single-instruction thread access ...

(Many GPU single-instruction can handle 16 Byte words (128bit) when it's known in advance, but most CPUs use single-instruction 32bits or 64bit limits)

I'm leaving aside the chance that threads might read from the CPU registers instead of the actual memory (ignoring updates to the data), these are mostly solvable using the `volatile` keyword in C.

However, conflicts and memory corruption can still happen.

Some memory storage operations are handled internally (by the CPU) or by your compiler (the machine code) using a number of storage calls.

In these cases, mostly on multi-core machines (but not only), there's the risk that the "reader" will receive information that was partially updated and has no meaning whatsoever (i.e., half of a pointer is valid and the other isn't).

Variables larger than 32 bits or 64 bits, will *usually* get updated a CPU "word" (not an OS word) at a time (32bits or 64 bits).

Byte sized variables are super safe, That's why they are are often used as flags... but they should probably be handled using the `atomic_*` store/write operations provided by the OS or the compiler.

Comment: Can "software transactional memory (STM)" solve the potential problems? Like what Clojure offers?

Comment: @mahdix - STM might protect you (since the logs and the data won't fit, so a rollback will be performed)... but this is usually a language feature. It can be implemented in C (probably is), but it's just an alternative to using locks... IMHO, not even a very good alternative. C will not automate the STM usage (which kinda beats it's purpose, if you ask me), so you'll have to surround every read and write operation with the STM logic.